# Get dates from json log file using JQ

Tags: json, powershell, jq

I have a huge file in this format:

```json
{
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Id": 1,
  "time": "2022-01-01T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
{
  "Name": "Homer",
  "Id": 2,
  "time": "2022-01-02T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
{
  "Name": "Bart",
  "Id": 3,
  "time": "2022-01-03T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
```

How can I filter this file by date range and specific period of time?
I was trying to solve this using jq, but was not able to do so. If there another way how to filter it without jq, please let me know.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the code you have tried so far? this will help us identify where you are going wrong. Also please let us know how you are receiving this json, is it via an API or file etc?

Comment: I get invalid json in powershell.  Shouldn't this be an array?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't a simple `select` do what you want? For example using plain string comparison makes easy date ranges inclusive on the left and exclusive on the right:

```sh
jq 'select(.time > "2022-01-01" and .time < "2022-01-03")'
```

```
{
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Id": 1,
  "time": "2022-01-01T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
{
  "Name": "Homer",
  "Id": 2,
  "time": "2022-01-02T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qGvuheFhxz)

You could also convert the date string into e.g. [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) ("seconds since the Epoch") using `fromdate` and operate on that as a number (after employing `sub` to cut off second fractions in order to obtain an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) compatible date):

```sh
jq 'select(.time | sub("\\.\\d+"; "") | fromdate < 1641100000)'
```

```json
{
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Id": 1,
  "time": "2022-01-01T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
{
  "Name": "Homer",
  "Id": 2,
  "time": "2022-01-02T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_4gvINOIW8)

Or, for the sake of another example, using `strptime` to convert the date into a broken-down array (containing in this order: year, (zero-based) month, day, hour, minute, second, day of week, and day of year) and then filtering e.g. for Mondays (represented as `1` in that array at the (zero-based) position `6`):

```sh
jq 'select(.time | sub("\\.\\d+"; "") | strptime("%FT%TZ") | .[6] == 1)'
```

```json
{
  "Name": "Bart",
  "Id": 3,
  "time": "2022-01-03T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3U44MhRBZF)

Answer (score 0):

A powershell example.  Taking the input as an array:

```
[{
  "Name": "Alex",
  "Id": 1,
  "time": "2022-01-01T04:29:18.9099882Z"
},
{
  "Name": "Homer",
  "Id": 2,
  "time": "2022-01-02T04:29:18.9099882Z"
},
{
  "Name": "Bart",
  "Id": 3,
  "time": "2022-01-03T04:29:18.9099882Z"
}]
```

For some reason in powershell 5, I have use parentheses to complete the conversion first (could use a lot of memory).  The time fields are converted to the .Net [datetime] type, and then it's easy to compare them.  The right side of a comparision automatically gets converted to a datetime if it can be.

```
(get-content file.json | convertfrom-json) | 
foreach-object { $_.time = [datetime]$_.time; $_ } | 
where-object { $_.time -ge '1/1/22' -and $_.time -le '1/2/22' }

Name  Id time
----  -- ----
Homer  2 1/1/2022 11:29:18 PM
```

Here's a workaround for the original file of consecutive json objects:

```
get-content file.json -ReadCount 5 | 
foreach-object { $_ | convertfrom-json } | 
foreach-object { $_.time = [datetime]$_.time; $_ } | 
where-object { $_.time -ge '1/1/22' -and $_.time -le '1/2/22' }
```